# Существует ли GUI лаунчер для батников?

Tags: windows, поиск-программ, bat, launcher

Я не программист, а админ и за пару лет работы настрочил кучу скриптов. Но они раскиданы по папкам и в них ориентируюсь только я. Иногда меня нет на работе и может возникнуть потребность запустить один из этих батников, а объяснять шефу, как один из них называется, в какой папке лежит, с каким флагом запускать (и вообще что такое батник) у меня нет сил и желания.

Я бы хотел сделать или найти лаунчер батников, чтобы все было как у людей: видишь описание -> нажимаешь кнопку -> батник запускается. Короче говоря, что-то вроде `Zenity` или `Yad` на Линуксах. И, желательно, что-нибудь портативно-компилируемое.

Comment: Поставьте метку [tag:поиск-программ], предварительно почитав её описание

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=47653

Answer (score 0):

Если вы спокойно пишете скрипты, напишите еще один скрипт. Сделайте там choice, составьте менюшку, и оставьте один ярлык. Защитите сам скрипт и ярлык к нему админскими правами. Когда ваш босс откроет этот файл, он должен увидеть "нажмите a, чтобы...". Меню можно сделать многоуровневым. Размер окна консоли редактируется в свойствах ярлыка. Я бы решил этот вопрос именно так.

На всякий случай пример использования choice с просторов интернета. Я добавил chcp для вашего удобства ;)

```
cls
chcp 1251
:start
ECHO.
ECHO 1. Print Hello
ECHO 2. Print Bye
ECHO 3. Print Test
set /p choice=Введите номер, чтобы вывести текст.
rem if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0;1%
if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%"  не является допустимым вариантом, попробуйте снова
if '%choice%'=='1' goto hello
if '%choice%'=='2' goto bye
if '%choice%'=='3' goto test
ECHO.
goto start
:hello
ECHO HELLO
goto end
:bye
ECHO BYE
goto end
:test
ECHO TEST
goto end
:end
pause
exit
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но я думал сделать какую-нибудь GUI-свистелку, чтобы у остальных вообще вопросов не было. Речь ведь идет о юзерах, которые _могут_ оказаться у машины, но которые могут не иметь понятия о том, что и как работает. Алсо, начитался Стака и нашел этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528775/14341375, наверное, это то, что мне подойдет.

Comment: Вы хотите обязательно добавить ещё один слой, да? Я считаю, что так еще и повышается риск падения безо всяких сообщений об ошибке, молчаливого несрабатывания и т.п. Вот вы сейчас заморочитесь и сделаете нечто на VC++, там будет system(). А в самом простом варианте с ВАТой пишете pause в конце - и любые ошибки на тарелочке с голубой каёмочкой.

Comment: Не хочу, но думаю исключительно о юзабилити в этом ключе. Потому что однажды на протяжении получаса из другого города пытался объяснить, как открыть командную строку и набрать команду. Даже если такое происходит раз в несколько месяцев -- это та вероятность, которую я хочу избежать. Так или иначе, за ответ спасибо, а в случае командлайна можно даже использовать какой-нибудь dialog.

Comment: >любые ошибки на тарелочке с голубой каёмочкой

Ошибки можно вывести в лог же.